# Can't send the image binary code from Power Apps through Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm following along the tutorial where I created the following formula for a "Submit" button in order to save the data, format the JPG files to the binary code, and send it through Power Automate to SharePoint.

However, I'm getting an error for both variables varImageTrimmed and varSigTrimmed that Image can't be converted into a numerical value. I guess it's something with the JSON() function, but can't figure out what exactly.

Any ideas?

```
SubmitForm(Form1) & Set(
   FormStat;
   "View"

) & ResetForm(Form1) & Set(
   SignaturePopUp;
   false

) & Set(
   varImage1;
   JSON(
      UploadedImage3.Image;
      JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData
   )

) & Set(
   varImageTrimmed;
   Mid(
      varImage1;
      2;
      Len(varImage1 - 2)
   )

) & Set(
   varSig1;
   JSON(
      PenInput1.Image;
      JSONFormat.IncludeBinaryData
   )

) & Set(
   varSigTrimmed;
   Mid(
      varSig1;
      2;
      Len(varSig1 - 2)
   )

) & UploadStuff.Run(
   DataCardValue1.Text;
   varImageTrimmed;
   varSigTrimmed
)
```

I expected pressing a button would transfer the images to the binary code, set variables, and send them to Power Automate, yet I'm getting
the following error for both variables - it says "cannot convert":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your "UploadStuff" flow, could you share a snip of it's trigger?
I would recommend upding your flow to use the "PowerApps (V2)" trigger which allows you to define the input parameters.